# What statistical test should be used for a therapy experiment?

Tags: statistics

I'm working on medical project where we propose a new therapy. I have two groups of patients A and B; A follows the usual therapy + the new one and B follows only the usual therapy. the data collected before and after the experiment are from using IMU (Inertial measurement unit) sensors of the patients during a movement activity (like walking). From this data I want to see if there is any improvement before and after the experiment. What are the appropriate statistical test I should use?

Answer (score 1):

You don't give much detail about the type of measurement or the size of your sample. But assuming the simple case of two reasonably large samples of measurements representing the two groups, and assuming an unknown distribution, I think the most standard option would be a [Wilcoxon signed rank test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test).